# solr: undefined field ------------------------------4566bce013ce

Tags: solr

I'm trying to upload csv file to index.  When I do I'm getting an error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field ----------------------------4566bce013ce
at org.apach.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getField(IndexSchema.java:1185)
```

I'm uploading the csv file via curl as follows:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/solrTest/update/csv -F commit=ture -F skipLine=1 -F stream.file=/home/solr/text.csv -F fieldnames=partId,desc,usage -H content-type:text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

All of my fields are defined in my schema.xml, so I'm not sure why I'm getting an undefined field error.

let me know if you need any more information, Thanks.

EDIT:
Ok, after reading the post by Itay Moav, I've decided to do some more simple test.  I'm using a csv file with only one record with a partId (test123).  My schema.xml look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="parts" version="1.5">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="text_en_us" class="solr.StrField">
  </types>
  <fields>
    <field name=partId type="text_en_us" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <uniqueKey>partId</uniqueKey>
  </fields>
</schema>
```

I'm getting the same error even with this test data.  the only thing that changes is the number at the end.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field ----------------------------------7951b21305c3
```

thanks again for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do a binary elimination of the records in the csv file, untill u r left only with the problematic record. Then u either see the problem by yourself, or post here the record and the schema

Answer (score 1):

Add this to our schema, this should fix it.

```
<types>
    <fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" />
    ....
</types>

<fields>
    <dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" />
    ....
<fields>
```

Comment: This will simply hide the problem instead of solving it

Comment: Yes, true, the topic starter actually is confident that he wants all the fields in, so yes, my suggestion does not fix it.